# SCSS exclusion in selector

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

I need to define CSS rules for one class as long as it's not inside another one, whatever tree depth is.
For example, I want my `.class` to be color: red unless it's inside a element with `.wrapper` class, and in that case color would be blue...

```
div.wrapper
 div
   div
     span.text ==> should be blue
```

```
div.wrapper
     span.text ==> should be blue
```

```
div.anything
 div
   div
     span.text ==> should be RED
```

I would like to get something better than redefining my rule like

```
.text {
  color: red
}
.wrapper .text {
  color: blue
}
```

Comment: What's wrong the rule you have last ?

Comment: Nothing. It works but, in my real case I have more than one rule and more than one selector to treat. That's why I ask help to know if I can find a way to right sort of duplicated code.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply nest your rules and put the [parent selector](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/parent-selector) at the end of your selector to reverse the nesting:

```
.text {
  color: red;

  .wrapper & {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

The code above will compile as:

```
.text {
  color: red;
}

.wrapper .text {
  color: blue;
}
```

Comment: thank you both of you. I already had these way to define it but, i wanted to ask if it would be possible to define it with one rule only in which I would set the color as long as element is not under .wrapper class in DOM tree, whatever the distance

Comment: Since there is not parent selector in CSS, I don't think that it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You have to select the two classes only. I've created a pen with the answer, just check it out. https://codepen.io/alac1984/pen/qBBGaKX

HTML

```
<div class="rect">
  <span class="redOrBlue">This text is red, no matter what dept;</span>
</div>

<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div class="rect">
       <span class="redOrBlue">This text is red, no matter what dept;</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="rect">
    <span class="redOrBlue">This text is blue</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
  display: inline-block;
}
.rect {
  margin: 10px 10px;
  position: relative;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  color:red;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.redOrBlue {
  color: red;
}

.wrapper .rect .redOrBlue {
  color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you posted the answer for the correct question?

Comment: Yes, I think so. What made you think I wouldn't?

Comment: The question is about `scss` syntax, not about a general `css` problem :)

Answer (score 0):

If both elements share a common class, then you can use CSS's Negation selector **:not()**.

```
.wrapper {

    &:not(.colored) .text {
      color: red;
    }
}
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrapper:not(.colored) .text {
  color: red;
}
```